How to control arrival rate with agent specific attributes in AnyLogic?
I have Person agent in GIS space and 3 facilities. Which person will go to which facility is determined outside of simulation (an attribute in Person 'facilityChoice'). For three facility I drew 3 process flow source -> moveTo -> queue -> delay -> sink. At each source, only the people specific to that facility are entering. Question: HOW CAN I CONTROL ARRIVAL RATE? The person agent has one attribute 'age'. I want to control the arrival rate based 'age'. For instance, if age is 65, arrival rate will be 5 per minute, if age is 20 then 1 per minute, and so on. Below is a model snapshot.

It is a bad idea to make the arrival rate of X depend on a characteristic of X.
Since your sources are creating Person agents, how would they "know" in advance what the next Persons age is?
You should change the setup such that you inject persons with different ages at different rates based on your data. Dynamic Events would typically be used for that but it is a bit advanced.
if you don't know what I mean, best just use different Source blocks with fixed rates for different age groups
